# How to send emails from different accounts through JavaMailSender (w/o user login)

Tags: java, spring-boot, email

I have a ***Contact Us*** form on my webpage where a user can enter their name, email address and a message to send me an email. However I do not have the user logged into their mailing account. Is it possible to generate and send an e-mail through their mailing account without logging in?

On the back-end, when I set the value for the ***From Email***, it is ignored and the email address used for sending the email is ***redacted@gmail.com***

MailSender.java

```
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendEmail(String fromEmail, String body, String subject) throws MessagingException{
        

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

        message.setFrom(fromEmail);
        message.setTo("redacted@gmail.com");
        message.setText(body);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        
        System.out.println("Mail sent successfully");
    }
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: "smtp.gmail.com"
    port: 587
    username: redacted@gmail.com
    password: redacted
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
            required: true
```

Comment: No. You have to log in. Because spam.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `from` part isn't your actual username or mail address. It's just the "display name" for the recipient.

Depending on the mail provider the `from` part must be identical to your username. In other cases it's fine to send mails with an arbitrary `from`. But most providers will reject this, because it can be a security risk for the receiver if they for example receive a mail from you, but their mail application shows `support@microsoft.com`. `;)`

The `from` part also can be used to add a real name in addition to the mail address which requires a special format (something like `My Name<redacted@gmail.com>`). In Java this can be done like this:

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("redacted@gmail.com", "My Name"));
```

But this again is highly dependent on your mail provider. Some will set this automatically for you. Some will require that it's identical to your user account data. And some will let you send whatever you want.

Btw: The same applies to `sentDate`. I don't think that Google allows you to provide a custom date, instead they will override it.

Comment: aha! I was thinking about directly replying to the clients emails who would contact me through the Contact Us form but now I understand that it is just a placeholder, for gmail at least since it can be a huge security issue. Thanks a lot Benjamin!